# ios coreText UILabel always loses last line of text

Tags: ios, uilabel, core-text

I am trying to use coretext to replicate UILabel text drawing in order to understand which words in the UILabel were tapped (ex: hashtags). My code works except it always underestimates the label's text by omitting the last line of text. I cannot figure out why despite days of headscratching.

Assume we have a CGPoint touched within our UILabel subview

```
CGRect textRect = [self textRectForBounds:self.bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:self.numberOfLines]; //Text rect is the text drawing window
textRect.origin.y = (self.bounds.size.height - textRect.size.height)/2;

CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)self.attributedText);
// Offset tap coordinates by textRect origin to make them relative to the origin of frame
point = CGPointMake(point.x - textRect.origin.x, point.y - textRect.origin.y);
// Convert tap coordinates (start at top left) to CT coordinates (start at bottom left)
point = CGPointMake(point.x, textRect.size.height - point.y);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, textRect);
CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, [self.attributedText length]), path, NULL);

CFArrayRef lines = CTFrameGetLines(frame);


NSInteger numberOfLines = self.numberOfLines > 0 ? MIN(self.numberOfLines, CFArrayGetCount(lines)) : CFArrayGetCount(lines);
```

Number of lines is always one less than appropriate, and point recognition works perfectly up until the last line of text (or, if text is one line, does not work at all)